# Error while reading json Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'output' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, pubnub, c3.js

I am trying to create a chart with c3.js using PUBNUB javascript SDK. The problem is that when I try to create a chart it wont read the json data I get the error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'output' of undefined.**

the complete data is (I am sending the data via python)

```
m = {
    "devices": [
        {
            "Name": "bdev0",
            "output": {
                "IO_Operations": 0,
                "Bytes_Read": 0,
                "Bytes_Written": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "Name": "bdev1",
            "output": {
                "IO_Operations": 0,
                "Bytes_Read": 0,
                "Bytes_Written": 0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

while the JavaScript is

```
eon.chart({
    pubnub   : pubnub,
    history  : false,
    channel  : 'chanel',
    flow     : true,
    generate : {
        bindto : '#chart_1',
        size: {
        height: 180,
        width: 500
    },
        data   : {
            x      : 'x',
            labels : true
        },
        axis : {
            x : {
                type : 'timeseries',
                tick : {
                    format : '%H:%M:%S'
                },
                zoom: {
                   enabled: true
                }
            }
        }
    },

    transform : function(m) {
        return { columns : [
            ['x', new Date().getTime()],
            ['Bytes Written', m.devices[i].output.Bytes_Read],
            ['Bytes Read', m.devices[i].output.Bytes_Written]


        ] };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `devices[i]`, but nowhere do you *define* what `i` is. You need to give `i` a value if you're going to use it as an array index.

Comment: using [i] meant that It goes through all elements in the array, when I try to do this in simple javascript it works, why is that? for instance see this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/umLwwq2a/

Comment: @Imo As I said, you need to **define `i`**. Your code in the fiddle does exactly that, so it works. The code you posted above **doesn't define `i`**, so *of course* it doesn't work. Try taking out the `for (var i` part from your JSFiddle and see how well it works.